# startupHook -- ambiguous type variable

Tags: xmonad

Stupid simple xmonad.hs question...

```
import XMonad

myTerminal = "gnome-terminal"
startupHook = do { spawn "/usr/bin/feh  --bg-fill /home/abennett/wallpaper.jpg"  }

main = xmonad defaults

defaults = defaultConfig {
        terminal = myTerminal
}
```

Throws this error:

```
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/abennett/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

xmonad.hs:4:20:
    Ambiguous type variable `m0' in the constraint:
      (MonadIO m0) arising from a use of `spawn'
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      Main.startupHook :: m0 () (bound at xmonad.hs:4:1)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      spawn "/usr/bin/feh  --bg-fill /home/abennett/wallpaper.jpg"
    In the expression:
      do { spawn "/usr/bin/feh  --bg-fill /home/abennett/wallpaper.jpg" }
    In an equation for `Main.startupHook':
        Main.startupHook
          = do { spawn
                   "/usr/bin/feh  --bg-fill /home/abennett/wallpaper.jpg" }

Please check the file for errors
```

I've tried things like `startupHook = startup` and then `startup = do { spawn "stuff" }` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the `startupHook` in your `defaults`. Either you specify it directly in `defaults`, or you create a variable and define your `startupHook` to be e.g.  `myStartupHook` in `defaults` (just as you did with your terminal):

```
import XMonad

main = xmonad defaults

defaults = defaultConfig {
    terminal = myTerminal,
    startupHook = myStartupHook
    }

myTerminal = "gnome-terminal"

myStartupHook = do 
    spawn "/usr/bin/feh  --bg-fill /home/abennett/wallpaper.jpg"
    -- and more stuff like
    spawn myTerminal
    spawn "xclock"
```

When you start using more workspaces, you might like to use `spawnOn` imported from `XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn`.

Please have a look at the [xmonad config template](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/Template_xmonad.hs_(0.9)), it will give you a better idea how to build your config file.